# Is the order for variadic template pack expansion defined in the standard?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I thought that expanding a [parameter pack](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) had the following behavior:

```
// for Args ... p
f(p)...;
// was equivalent to
f(p1); f(p2); ...; f(pn);
```

But I just found out that gcc (4.6, 4.7 and 4.8) does it the other way around:

```
f(pn); ...; f(p2); f(p1);
```

Whereas clang does it as I expected.

Is that a bug in GCC or are they both valid according to the standard?

***Minimal example***

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
bool print(const unsigned index, const T& value){
  std::cerr << "Parameter " << index << " is " << value << std::endl; 
  return true;
}

template<typename ... Args>
void printAll(Args ... args){
  unsigned i = 0;
  [](...){}(print(i++, args)...);
}

int main(){
  int a = 1; float b = 3.14; std::string c("hello");
  printAll(a, b, c);
}
```

Compiling and executing:

```
$> clang++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
$> ./test
Parameter 0 is 1
Parameter 1 is 3.14
Parameter 2 is hello
$> g++ -std=c++11 -o test test.cpp
$> ./test
Parameter 0 is hello
Parameter 1 is 3.14
Parameter 2 is 1
```

***Answer***

It didn't take long for Martinho Fernandes to spot the error here. The problem is the order of evaluation of parameters, which is not defined by the standard (1.9.3):

> Certain other aspects and operations of the abstract machine are described in this International Standard as
>   unspecified (for example, order of evaluation of arguments to a function).

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56774

Comment: That is a know gcc bug. Gcc 4.8.x has fixed that BUT introduced a new problem with this fix! See #59716 in bugzilla. This bug will not be fixed in the near future! Nobody has read this entry for month :-)

Comment: No, this is not a bug in GCC. There was a bug that also caused unwanted results, but who cares? It's not what causes this behaviour as the bug linked didn't exist in the 4.6 line. The test is broken, period.

Comment: See also: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0acad286b78429a1. No bug.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Thanks for submitting a solution. I opted for a pack traversal instead, which probably gets compiled to the same thing in the end: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92616104b790a942

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Is the order for variadic template pack expansion defined in the standard?

Yes. The expanded elements are in an order that corresponds to the original order of the pack.

In the test, the expansion `[](...){}(print(i++, args)...);` is equivalent to: `[](...){}(print(i++, a), print(i++, b), print(i++, c));`.

The test is flawed in that it tests the order of evaluation of function arguments, which is a completely different matter. If you try and execute the expanded form presented above, you will observe the same behaviour. Or you would if the code didn't have undefined behaviour, since the variable `i` is incremented several times without the increments being sequenced.